# Problem with DeleteCases

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, pattern-matching

I'm about to report this as a bug but wondered what you would make of it.  Works as expected in version 7.

```
Union@Map[DeleteCases[#, False] &, ConstantArray[{1}, 99]]
```

> {{1}}

```
Union@Map[DeleteCases[#, False] &, ConstantArray[{1}, 100]]
```

> {{}}

Comment: Very interesting. It is seems related to `Map` autocompiling as `TracePrint` with `TraceInternal-True` suggests.

Comment: I see the Compile option ... Adding Evaluate forces the correct result, i.e. `Map[Evaluate@DeleteCases[#...`

Comment: I believe there are "compilation thresholds" which trigger at certain values, i.e. 99 to 100. I think there's an option to control the value it triggers at, but I always forget it. In any event, I think the output of the second is a bug, introduced at this "compilation threshold".

Comment: Definitely due to the compiling but must be a bug: `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"MapCompileLength" -> 110}]`

Comment: This bug has been reported to Wolfram support.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen of course `Evaluate` forces the correct result, but it is correct only by accident, since now it will not delete any `False` entries.. `Evaluate@DeleteCase[#,False]&` evaluates to `#&`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Oops. I thought it was affecting the Compile in Map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the recently [released](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/04/16/version-12-launches-today-big-jump-for-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/) version 12.0.

```
Union@Map[DeleteCases[#, False] &, ConstantArray[{1}, 100]]             
(* {{1}} *)
```